# Why is, when I use vee-validate with locales the field undefined?

Tags: vuejs3, vee-validate, nuxt3

I use see-validate with locales. If the field is required it shows "The undefined field is required" and if it is not a valid email "The undefined field must be a valid email".

So it use the validation but can not find the field name. How I can fix my Problem?

My Field is:

```
<Field name="email" v-slot="{ field, errors }" v-model="form.email" rules="required|email">
    <v-text-field id="login-input-email" class="input-field placeholder-center font-italic"          variant="plain" :placeholder="$t('login.input.email.placeholder')" v-bind="field" :error-messages="errors" >
</v-text-field>
</Field>
```

My vee-validate.js:

```
import { localize, setLocale } from '@vee-validate/i18n';

import en from '@vee-validate/i18n/dist/locale/en.json';
import de from '@vee-validate/i18n/dist/locale/de.json';

import localesEN from '~/locales/en';
import localesDE from '~/locales/de';

    export default defineNuxtPlugin(nuxtApp => {
        configure({
            generateMessage: localize({
                en: Object.assign(en, localesEN.validation),
                de: Object.assign(de, localesDE.validation)
            })
        });
.....
```

I have tried names: {email: 'Email'} in en:{} to get the name in my field. That doesn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like VeeValidate does not take the fieldname by default and is waiting a "name" props

So I did this :

```
configure({
  generateMessage: ctx => {
    const localizeFn = localize({ en, fr, es, it })
    return localizeFn({ ...ctx, name: ctx.field })
  }
})
```

VeeValidate send a "context" on generateMessage with the informations. One of them is "field", which is the field name
but localize need a "name" prop, and there is none on the context data